# Integral Help - $\int \frac {\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}{u}du$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

As per the integral table, how do I show $\int \frac {\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}{u}du$ = $  {\sqrt{u^2-a^2}} - \arccos^{-1}(\frac {a}{u})+c$

I can't figure out how to start it.

I can do it for:
$$
\int \frac {\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}{u}du
 = \sqrt{u^2-a^2} - \mathrm{arcsec}^{-1}(\frac{u}{a})+c
$$
by starting with $\mathrm{arcsec}\ \theta = u$

Is it just a matter of showing the relationship between $\mathrm{arcsec}$ and $\arccos$?

Comment: $\textrm{arcsec}^{-1}$ does not quite make sense. It should be either $\textrm{arcsec}$ or $\sec^{-1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep. Since $\sec x=1/\cos x$, if we set $$\sec x=1/\cos x=y,$$
then $$x=\sec^{-1}y$$
and $$x=\cos^{-1}\frac1y,$$
so $\sec^{-1}y=\cos^{-1}\frac1y$.

Answer (score 0):

You can think it like a right triangle with hypotenuse $u$ and base $a$, such that $\cos x=\frac{a}{u}$, where $x$ is the angle between hypotenuse and side $a$. Then from this you have $u = a\cdot\sec x$ and $du = a\cdot \sec x\cdot\tan x\cdot dx$, with $0<x<\pi/2$. Plugging this on the integral finally you get:
$$a\int \tan^2 xdx=a\int (\sec^2 x - 1)dx=a\tan x - ax$$
From right trianle $\tan x = \sqrt{u^2-a^2}/a$ and $x = \sec^{-1}(u/a)$, so replacing finally we get
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{u^2-a^2}}{u}du = \sqrt{u^2-a^2}-a\sec^{-1}\big(\frac{u}{a}\big)+c$$